# How to load function from string named module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have structure:

```
modules
    __init__.py
    version_1.py
    version_2.py
settings.py
my_script.py
__init__.py
```

In file version_1 and version_2 I have two versions the same function:

```
def ext_function(*args, **kwargs):
    # something
```

I want to define in file settings.py what version have been loaded:

```
EXT_MODULE = 'modules.version_1'
```

and execute function in my_script like this:

```
settings.EXT_MODULE.ext_function(args)
```

How to do it? EXT_MODULE is a string so I can not execute function like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `importlib` module:

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module(settings.EXT_MODULE)
module.ext_function(args)
```